# How to get user access token though server-side authentication

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-access-token

How can I get user access token though server-side authentication Facebook sdk. I have faced this error:

> **Catchable fatal error:** Argument 1 passed to Facebook\Helpers\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper::__construct() must be an instance of Facebook\Authentication\OAuth2Client, string given, called in /home/ds09/public_html/adopted/newsiteadmin/facebook_sdk_api/examples/access_token.php on line 50 and defined in /home/ds09/public_html/adopted/newsiteadmin/facebook_sdk_api/src/Facebook/Helpers/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php on line 75

Thanks for help in advance

Comment: Please read this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted

Comment: Thanks for help, but this page provide the solutions using login pop up box, but i need to get the user access token through coding. this is used in scheduler, please help.

Comment: You can't. It is not possible

Comment: No its possible . please see this url
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/authentication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook does not provide the user access token without any user intervention, My requirement is to get the access token through programming  which i use in scheduler.

But i get the task done through a different way, In this way you do not need to get the user access token every-time when you do some API operation, You can get it one time manually from Facebook and use this forever.

This is the [link](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/) where you can get the user access token for your app and you can verify it on this [link](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check this page, it help me a lot.

Begin first checking the Requirements:

1. Check the hosting **PHP version 5.4** or higher
2. Check **mbstring** enabled and the values

https://benmarshall.me/facebook-php-sdk/#requirements

Comment: Thanks tony for helping me.